# Calculate "ranking quality" for evaluation of algorithm

Tags: ranking, model-evaluation

I have a table with 15 items with attributes. The items are ranked, the rank is kind of the label. Now I build several algorithms, that get the 15 items in an un-ordered and tries to rank them. So far so good, but how can I evaluate/compare different rankings? Which one is better?

Example:

```
Original       Model 1 Results:   Model 2 Results:
Item | Rank    Item | Rank        Item | Rank
A    | 1       A    | 2           A    | 1
B    | 2       B    | 1           B    | 3
C    | 3       C    | 3           C    | 4
D    | 4       D    | 5           D    | 2
E    | 5       E    | 4           E    | 5

Which Model's ranking is closer to the original?
```

I already found [Mean_reciprocal_rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank), but it only seems to consider the best (rank 1) result.

What other options do I have to compare the rankings in order to evaluate and find my best ranking method?

Thanks!

PS: I'm pretty new to analytics, sorry if I'm not using correct terms or my questions seems to be stupid.

Cheers!

Comment: google this: Kendall’s Tau and Spearman’s Rank Correlation Coefficient

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the *standard deviation*, taking the square root of the average of the squared deviations of the ranking positions from their final value.

If the final ranking is *a-b-c-d-e*, you'll have

$\sigma_1 = \sqrt { {1+1+0+1+1} \over {5}}= 0.89 $ for *b-a-c-e-d*

$\sigma_2 = \sqrt { {0+4+1+1+0} \over {5}} = 1.10 $ for *a-d-b-c-e*

showing that the first model is better, even if it has four *errors* (while second model has three and correctly identify the first position).

Comment: I think you have an error for the second one since rank change for D is 2, not 4, and this way it is 0 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 0 which is the same as the first model.

Comment: Using your words, "rank change" for *d* is 2, so its *squared deviation* is 4, in fact. :)

Comment: My bad, forgot about the square. Anyway, I like and appreciate your answers :)